# Bigserial does not change when some rows are deleted in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres schema where I have a table which has an index denoted as BIGSERIAL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Class(
    id BIGSERIAL,
    roll SMALLINT,

    PRIMARY_KEY(roll)
)
```

When I delete some rows of Class by id the id does not get reset. So the row numbers
look like 0,1,2,3,5,6...
Is there a way to reset the table id the moment we delete a record?

I tried

```
alter sequence class_id_seq restart with 1;
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Why would you want to reset the counter? And if only row 3 is deleted should this be reused?

Comment: That's expected and intended. Nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

The entire purpose of [`smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) types and [`int generated by default as identity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.6.2.19.1.2) is to save you having to create, maintain and handle the sequence.

If you want to fetch specific rows based on their position in a continuous sequence, use an [`order by`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) clause with [`offset`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) and [`limit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html). This skips the first 5 rows and gives you the 6th:

```sql
select * from class order by id offset 5 limit 1;
```

Even though the `id` column in the table has gaps in its sequence, it maintains the ascending order. If the field is meant to be an indication of insert/creation time [(make sure you're checking the time right)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), best define it as `id timestamp default now()`, making it exactly that.

You can hide the table behind a view that always shows a gapless sequence of `id`s by attaching a [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). This lets you target it directly in `where`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wL9e5BDc)

```sql
create view v_class as select row_number()over(order by id),* from class;

select * from v_class where row_number=6;
```

The column is recomputed each time you query the view, but it's still better than trying to recompute and maintain the column in a [`trigger after insert or update or delete on "Class" for each statement`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).